# Add Header Footer on each page of a pdf from html using Barryvdh Laravel package

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I am going to create a pdf file from HTML using the Barryvdh Laravel package. I need to add a header and footer to each page as this is a multi-page document.

Answer (score -1):

I've looked around a bit and I think that the two links below will help you solve your problem: 
1- https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/139#issuecomment-369050826

Create a route that renders the html for the header/footer, and pass the full url to that route as option.

```
$html = view()->make("juiztramp.exporter.pdf.grupos")
            ->with("provas",$ordens_de_passagem)
            ->render();

$headerHtml = view()->make('juiztramp.exporter.pdf.header')
            ->with('nomeEvento',  $nomeEvento)
            ->with('dataEvento',  $dataEvento)
            ->with('localEvento', $localEvento)
            ->render();

$footerHtml = view()->make('juiztramp.exporter.pdf.footer')
            ->with('organizacao', $organizacao)
            ->render();
```

And later on

```
$options = [
            'orientation'   => 'portrait',
            'encoding'      => 'UTF-8',
            'header-html'   => $headerHtml,
            'footer-html'   => $footerHtml,

            // further options....
        ];

return response(
            $snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html, $options),
            200,
            [
                'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
//                'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"',
                'Content-Disposition'   => 'filename="'.$filename.'"',
            ]
        );
```

example header view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 200px; background-color: #00be67;"> {{ $nomeEvento }} </td>
                <td style="width: 500px; background-color: #0a94e3;" align="center"> {{ $localEvento }} </td>
                <td style="width: 200px; background-color: #7b3f25" align="right"> {{ $dataEvento }} </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>an
```